# How to add PHP code to a URL

Tags: php

What php code should I use and how should I add it to the **NEXT ARTICLE** url link below, that will cause the next article in the multidimensional array to be echoed back subsequently?

I intend to echo back one article after another sequentially.

Thank you!

(form.php)

```
<form action="process.php" method="get">
    Group:
    <select name="group">
        <option value="group1">Group1</option>
        <option value="group2">Group2</option>
    </select>

    Chapter:
    <input type="text" name="chapter">

    Article:
    <input type="text" name="article">

    <input type="submit" value="Go to Article">    

</form>
```

(process.php)

```
<?php

session_start();

$laws=array(
       "group1"=>array(
                      "1"=>array(
                                "1"=>"This is article (1) in chapter (1) of (group1)",
                                "2"=>"This is article (2) in chapter (1) of (group1)",
                                "3"=>"This is article (3) in chapter (1) of (group1)",
                                ),
                      "2"=>array(
                                "1"=>"This is article (1) in chapter (2) of (group1)",
                                "2"=>"This is article (2) in chapter (2) of (group1)",
                                "3"=>"This is article (3) in chapter (2) of (group1)",
                                ),
                       ),
       "group2"=>array(
                      "1"=>array(
                                "1"=>"This is article (1) in chapter (1) of (group2)",
                                "2"=>"This is article (2) in chapter (1) of (group2)",
                                "3"=>"This is article (3) in chapter (1) of (group2)",
                                ),
                      "2"=>array(
                                "1"=>"This is article (1) in chapter (2) of (group2)",
                                "2"=>"This is article (2) in chapter (2) of (group2)",
                                "3"=>"This is article (3) in chapter (2) of (group2)",
                                ),

       )
       );

$grp= $_GET['group'];
$chap = $_GET['chapter'];
$art = $_GET['article'];

if(isset($laws[$grp]) && isset($laws[$grp][$chap]) && isset($laws[$grp][$chap][$art])){
$_SESSION['group'] = $grp;
$_SESSION['chapter'] = $chap;
$_SESSION['article'] = $art;    
}else{
$_SESSION['group'] = 'group1';
$_SESSION['chapter'] = '1';
$_SESSION['article'] = '1';   
}

$group = $_SESSION['group'];
$chapter = $_SESSION['chapter'];
$article = $_SESSION['article'];


echo $laws[$group][$chapter][$article]; // ALL NEXT ARTICLES TO BE ECHOED HERE!!!!!

?>

<a href="process.php" style="text-decoration: none;">NEXT ARTICLE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="process.php?group=<?php echo $group; ?>&chapter=<?php echo $chapter; ?>&article=<?php echo ($article + 1); ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">NEXT ARTICLE</a>
```

Will link to the next article in the chapter. You do however have to check you're not on the last article for a given chapter, which I'll leave to you

Comment: I have corrected your code to echo $article++ NOT echo ($article +1) and it has worked. But I also later added the PREVIOUS ARTICLE url link with the same code except $article-- but could not work. What should I do to make both links active and workable?